# Java RegEx To Match A Pattern Of Two Characters On Either End Of A Variable

Tags: java, regex, string

I can have any combination of `&@` and `@&` including `&`, `@`, and even  i.e. nothing preceding and proceeding a variable name such as `&@ClaimNumber@&`

I am already able to successfully locate the pattern `&@ClaimNumber@&`using the following code:

```
        Pattern regexPattern = Pattern.compile("&@" + element.trim() + "@&");
        Matcher patternMatcher = regexPattern.matcher(content);
        if(!patternMatcher.find() && !additionalVariables.contains(element)){
            errors.add(element);
        }
```

However, attempts to match `ClaimNumber@&` or `@ClaimNumber@&` fail when doing the following:

```
        regexPattern = Pattern.compile("@" + element.trim() + "@&");
        patternMatcher = regexPattern.matcher(content);

        if(patternMatcher.matches() && !additionalVariables.contains(element)){
            errors.add(element);
        }
```

Using `patternMatcher.find()` doesn't work and neither does `patternMatcher.matches()`

Is there a `Regular Expression` that will allow me to discover instances of incorrectly formed variables such as the following:

```
&ClaimNumber&, &@ClaimNumber, @ClaimNumber&, etc. there of all sixteen variations.
```

Comment: Maybe you need to use `(?<!&@)claimno(?!@&)` with `.find()`?

Comment: `regexPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!&@)" + element.trim() + "(?!@&)");` doesn't work.

Comment: Don't work how? Do you mean there must be at least  one `@` or `&` on one of the sides of the `claim#`? But not `&@claim@&`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I mean the variable can be bounded by nothing as in `variable` or as in `&variable` or `@variable&` or even `variable@&`

Comment: Check t[his approach](http://ideone.com/ktBaNM).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your RegEx is grabbing everything in the HTML document.  Will the following RegEx be more specific to what I am looking for?: `"&@\\w+@&|[&@]{0,2}" + element.trim() + "[&@]{0,2}"`                        Also, how can I grab the first two character before and after the matched variable such as `@Variable@&`?

Comment: 1) Do not run regex against HTML, parse it first with appriate tools, or make sure the HTML tags are ignored the same way I showed in the regex: match what you do not need and match & capture what you need; 2) To get parts of a match, use capturing groups: `"&@\\w+@&|([&@]{0,2})" + element.trim() + "([&@]{0,2})"` - now, Group 1 will contain `$` or `&` etc. before the element and Group 2 will contain the `&`/`@` after the element.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var value = "&one& &two@ @three@ @four& five@ @six &seven &@eight nine&@ @&ten&@";
var matches = value.match(
     new RegExp("\\b\\w+\\b", "g")
);
document.writeln(matches);
```

This will work \b\w+\b if you know you have space separated variables of that type as \b matches with boundaries and it includes & and @ as a boundary,it also requires that the variables be word character only but this can be changed by using  \b[\w]+\b and inserting any other characters you want included in your variable in the square brackets e.g \b[\w,]+\b would allow comers.

Comment: The Variables won't appear as you specify but rather throughout an HTML document such as `</B> &Variable@&</TD>`.  Will your RegEx Expression match this just `&Variable@&`?  Also, what is RegExp?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("([&@]{1,2})(\\w+)([@&]{1,2})");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(content);

while (mat.find()) {
    if (!additionalVariables.contains(mat.group(2))) {
        errors.add(mat.group(2));
    }
}
```

`[&@]{1,2}` means 1  or 2 of some combination of & or @, so it would match &, @, @&, &@, and the other combinations of up to 2 of those characters. The matched variable is in group 2. The prefix is in group 1; the suffix is in group 3

Comment: The variable is being added to errors through `errors.add(mat.group(1));`     Is there a way to add the discovered prefix and suffix along with the variable as in discovered `ClaimNumber@` and was added to errors?           Also, can the RegEx match the absence of prefix and suffix such as `ClaimNumber`?

Comment: I updated the answer for your first question. You can use basic string manipulation to combine the groups to your liking. The regex does not handle the absence of prefix or suffix, but you can put \\b around the \\w+ and make it 0,2 instead of 1,2. But that would leave you with just words and you wouldn't know the difference between what is supposed to be a variable and what is not.